# How to convert image into base64 and save it I am trying alot to convert my image to base 64 in RNFS system but UNABLE TO DO THAT REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, image, react-hooks, data-conversion

How to convert image into base64 and save it  I am trying alot to convert my image to base 64 in RNFS system but it gives error and not converting it.

const openCamera =async () => {
let source ;

```
let options = {
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};
launchCamera(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    alert(response.customButton);
  } else {
    source = JSON.stringify(response.assets[0].uri);
    console.log('Junaid', JSON.stringify(response.assets[0].uri));
   

  }

  // console.log('Khan',source);
  var data = RNFS.readFile( response.assets[0].uri, 'base64').
  then(res => { console.log('CODE IS NOW  ',data) });
 


});}
```

Comment: Package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker provided `base64` out of the box. You should try it if applicable to your project

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel i HAVE USED THAT ONE BUT UNABLE TO CONVERT THE IMAGE BY ITS URI